# Reduce power noise on AVR

Tags: power-supply, avr, noise

I'm working on an AVR computer, everything works fine, except when I tap any ground point with my finger (there are a lot of them exposed), the MCU (an ATMEGA328) hangs for a brief second. I have a feeling its the crystal, since I didn't put any capacitors on it. Also, when I tap the ground with an inductor on my finger, the MCU hangs for less time, then goes into turbo-charged speed. The only thing filtering the supply is 2 680uf capacitors on the main supply, then a 1uf capacitor for the MCU. And one more thing, the MCU will only run for several seconds, then freeze if the battery is almost dead, but everything else still runs perfectly. Can anybody help me design a better power filter for my next design?[image: The power circuit]

Comment: I would assume something is terribly wrong here; I have never ever seen a behavior like this. Why not go with the Schematic Checklist from Altium for your AVR. There are some for the UC3 family and I would assume they also provide something (datasheet, checklist, ...) for your AVR (whichever that is)

Comment: First make sure your power supply is in order before troubleshooting anything else. Add a 100nF ceramic decoupling cap near the power pins of the controller. Also add the load capacitors to the crystal (2 × ~15pF) and

Comment: You are aware that mF are huge capacitors? Are you sure you don't mean μF?

Comment: @jippie Yeah, I don't know where the micro symbol is.

Comment: [rightAlt][m] or, when using regular letters, it is more common to use an lower letter `u` than using a lower letter `m`.

Comment: If you could post a circuit, that would help out a whole lot.  There might be something wrong with your power stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an image how I always use a voltage regulater. I would also recommend to connect a (ceramic) capacitor of about 22pF between the crystal pins and the ground. I also put a ceramic capacitor of 0.1µF between the Vss and Vdd pins of the microcontroller itself.

Hope this helps.

[image: 5V regulator]

Comment: Thank you SO much! Would it help to put inductors at the MCU's power and ground, too?

Comment: you're welcome ;) I think, but I'm not quite sure, that inductors won't help much. Capacitors have a low resistance for high frequency (like power noise). In other words, the capacitor is a short circuit for high frequeny voltages.